# File permissions: Problems with SGID

Tags: linux, debian

I have set a directory's SGID and every file created in this directory get the directory's group instead of the users one.
That works perfect.
But i want to do the same when a user edits the file.
Right now when a user edits and saves the file, the file takes user's group instead.

Shouldn't SGID take care of this as well?

Answer (score 0):

SGID should take care of this. As far as file is created within directory with SGID it inherits its group. The same for files being copied to dir.

Maybe, this could be caused by the way editor updates file after being saved - for example, if it maintains temporary edit buffer elsewhere, then saves it and then moves it to directory (although it seems weird). In such case, files being moved to dir with sgid keep their original group.

Comment: the change in this file happens through sftp..maybe this has something to do with it?or i might have screw up sth else..it supposed to work:/